# Capistrano recipe to automatically run deploy:cleanup only when needed

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano, webistrano

We do over 20 deployments a day using capistrano (actually [webistrano](https://github.com/peritor/webistrano/wiki/)) and we have a problem where the disk space on our servers get full of old deployment folders.

Every now and again I run the `deploy:cleanup` task to clean out all deployments (it keeps the last `:keep_releases`, currently set to 30). I would like to automate the cleanup.

One solution would be to add the following to the recipe to automatically run the cleanup after every deployment:

```
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"
```

**But**, I don't want to do this after *every* deployment, I'd like to limit it to only when the number of previous deployments gets to a threashold, e.g. 70. Does anyone know how I can do this?

---

Thoughts:

- Does Capistrano provide a variable that holds the number of previous deployments?

  - If not, does anyone know a way to calculate it. i.e. `set :num_releases, <what-can-I-put-here-to-count-previous-deployments>`
- Is there a way to pimp `deploy:cleanup` so it uses a minimum threshold, i.e. exit if `< :max_releases` previous deployments (where `:max_releases` is different from `:keep_releases`).
- Could the `except` keyword be used? i.e. something like `:except => { :num_releases < 70}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Does Capistrano provide a variable that holds the number of previous deployments?*

Yes, `releases.length`

> *Is there a way to pimp deploy:cleanup so it uses a minimum threshold?*

Yes, here is a privately namespaced task that will trigger the normal cleanup task ONLY if a certain number of release folders have built up:

```
namespace :mystuff do
  task :mycleanup, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    thresh = fetch(:cleanup_threshold, 70).to_i
    if releases.length > thresh
      logger.info "Threshold of #{thresh} releases reached, runing deploy:cleanup."
      deploy.cleanup
    end
  end
end
```

To have this run automatically after a deploy, put this at the top of the recipe:

```
after "deploy", "mystuff:mycleanup"
```

The good thing about this is that, `before` and `after` directives set on `deploy:cleanup` are executed as normal. For example we require the following:

```
before 'deploy:cleanup', 'mystuff:prepare_cleanup_permissions'
after 'deploy:cleanup', 'mystuff:restore_cleanup_permissions'
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty approach using the current capistrano code:

Change the cleanup task in https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb#L405 into this:

```
  task :cleanup, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    thresh = fetch(:cleanup_threshold, 70).to_i
    count = fetch(:keep_releases, 5).to_i
    if thresh >= releases.length
      logger.important "no old releases to clean up"
    else
      logger.info "threshold of #{thresh} releases reached, keeping #{count} of #{releases.length} deployed releases"

      directories = (releases - releases.last(count)).map { |release|
        File.join(releases_path, release) }.join(" ")

      try_sudo "rm -rf #{directories}"
    end
  end
```

and then you will be able to add

```
set :cleanup_threshold, 70
```

to your deployment recipe.